# A function passes all these unit tests, why is it failing in its actual context with the same parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

I'm making a simple API to cipher text through the Caesar cipher, on Javascript with Express.js. Testing the output with Jest, it appears to pass all the tests (and a console.log of the output indeed shows that the output string matches the expected string). However, when testing the relevant endpoint with Postman, the output doesn't match the expected string. I don't even know where to start digging, honestly.

Here is the route:

```
  const plaintext = req.body.text
  const factor = req.body.factor
  if (/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(plaintext) === false) {
    res.json({
      error: 'Your text contains forbidden characters! Please use only letters from A to Z',
    })
  } else {
    res.json({ message: caesar(plaintext, factor) })
  }
})
```

Here's the function:

```
const max = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0)
const lowerMin = 'a'.charCodeAt(0)
const lowerMax = 'z'.charCodeAt(0)

module.exports = {
  caesar: (plaintext, factor) => {
    let cipher = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < plaintext.length; i++) {
      plaintext.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && plaintext.charCodeAt(i) <= 90
        ? (cipher += String.fromCharCode(
            ((plaintext.charCodeAt(i) - min + factor) % (max - min + 1)) + min
          ))
        : plaintext.charCodeAt(i) >= 97 && plaintext.charCodeAt(i) <= 122
        ? (cipher += String.fromCharCode(
            ((plaintext.charCodeAt(i) - lowerMin + factor) % (lowerMax - lowerMin + 1)) + lowerMin
          ))
        : (cipher += plaintext[i])
    }
    return cipher
  },
}
```

The tests:

```
test('Ciphers the whole alphabet to ROT13, equalling "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM"', () => {
  expect(caesar('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 13)).toBe('NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM')
})

test('Ciphers "ABCXYZ" to ROT13, equalling "NOPKLM"', () => {
  expect(caesar('ABCXYZ', 13)).toBe('NOPKLM')
})

test('Ciphers "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet" to "Yberz Vcfhz Qbybe Fvg Nzrg" on ROT13', () => {
  expect(caesar('Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet', 13)).toBe('Yberz Vcfhz Qbybe Fvg Nzrg')
})

test('Ciphers "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet" to "Twzmu Qxacu Lwtwz Aqb Iumb" on ROT8', () => {
  expect(caesar('Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet', 8)).toBe('Twzmu Qxacu Lwtwz Aqb Iumb')
})
```

And the output of some queries:

Text: Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet |
Factor: 13 |
Output:

```
    "message": "Vjxxr Hftlr Bjvjx Thp Nrxp"
}
```

Text: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |
Factor: 13 |
Output:

```
{
    "message": "NJFBXTPLHDZVRNJFBXTPLHDZVR"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between test cases and API route is that `factor` isn't parsed and thus is allowed to be a string.

Type coercion makes this line

```
((plaintext.charCodeAt(i) - lowerMin + factor) % (lowerMax - lowerMin + 1)) + lowerMin
```

concatenate `plaintext.charCodeAt(i) - lowerMin` and `factor` strings, the result is converted to a number.

It should be:

```
const factor = +req.body.factor
```

`factor` can be additionally validated to be positive integer.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem! I used a `parseInt()` to change typing on `factor` and fixed it, many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Notice that parseInt can cause NaN. Needs to be addressed as well, at least with `parseInt(factor) || 0`, or `Math.trunc(factor)`, or `~~factor`.